# Alternative to writing data to S3 using Kinesis Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to write some IOT data to the S3 bucket and so I know 2 options so far.

**1) Use AWS CLI and put data directly to the S3.**

The downside of this approach is that I would have to parse out the data and figure out how to write it to S3. So there would be some dev required here. The upside is that there isn't additional cost associated to this.

**2) Use Kinesis firehose**

The downside of this approach is that it costs more money. It might be wasteful because the data doesn't have to be transferred in the real time, and it's not a huge amount of data. The upside is that I don't have to write any code for this data to be written in the S3 bucket.

Is there another alternative that I can explore?

Comment: From where is the data coming? Are they separate IoT devices sending data at regular intervals, or are they creating a daily file of information? In what format do you want the data saved in S3? What type of app is collecting the data on the device? If it is a normal programming language (eg Python), it is relatively simple to send data to S3.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at keeping costs low, can you use some sort of cron functionality on your IoT device to POST data to a Lambda function that writes to S3, possibly?

Option 2 with Kinesis Data Firehose has the least administrative overhead.

You may also want to look into the native IoT services. It may be possible to use IoT Core and put the data directly in S3.